# Is it possible to apply jquery to content rendered by external php (ajax)?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

page-one.php contains such jquery

```
$.post("___for_ajax_process.php", data_to_send_ajax_post, function(data_edit_content) {
$('#show_result').html(data_edit_content);
});
```

in `#show_result` i see content from `___for_ajax_process.php`

Rendered content contains many checkboxes and want to create check all. check all is named `draft_check_all`.

At first want to check what happens if I click the checkbox.

```
$("#draft_check_all").click(function(){
alert ( 'click test' );
});
```

And I do not see `alert ( 'click test' );` No popup at all.

Then View source and I do not see source code for content rendered by `___for_ajax_process.php`

As understand in such way can not apply jquery to content from `___for_ajax_process.php`? What if place `$("#draft_check_all").click(function(){` in `___for_ajax_process.php`? Are there any solutions for such situation?

**Solution**

placed jquery in external php and all works!

Answer (score 0):

A better solution would be event delegation.

```
$('#show_result').on('click', '#draft_check_all', function () {
  ... 
});
```